# Using a image to execute a js function

Tags: javascript, html, image

Hello I'm attempting to shutdown my Raspberry pi through web
I made a shutdown icon which opens a modal 
With a shutdown and Reboot image
I want to make those two images execute a Cgi script 
Off.cgi and reb.cgi  On click 
Here's a code I tried

```js
var xmlhttp; xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
function shutdown(){
   xmlhttp.open("GET","cgi-bin/off.cgi",true);
   xmlhttp.send();    
}                                                                      
function reboot(){
   xmlhttp.open("GET","cgi-bin/reb.cgi",true);
   xmlhttp.send();     
}
```

```html
<!-- Modal content -->     
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span> 
<h1>Do you Really want to Turn off or Reboot?</h1>
<p><img src="shutdown.png" height="150" width="150" onclick="shutdown()" /><img src="reboot.png" height="150" width="150" onclick ="reboot()"/></p>
```

Any ideas the problem here is it won't execute the js function

Comment: How do you know the functions are not executed? Aside, letting arbitrary visitors to access your server outside of the webroot might not be a good idea.

Comment: The function executes a cgi script It will change the mode of gpio pins and then turns off my Rpi so neither of these doesnt happen then I suspect function isn't executed

Comment: Hit F12 to see if any errors occur.

Comment: You can't call scripts to run on a server directly from the browser. Instead, create a backend route, send your request to that route and let the server side code call the script

Comment: Teemu,  there is a internal server Error saying it can't access my script But I can execute the other script called from a javascript  even to which the browser says internal server error

Comment: Thanks for the Tip baao      Problem solved

Comment: @baao Afaik you can configure your server to accept a path to outside of the webroot. That's what I suspected OP had done ...

Comment: @Teemu yeah, I think that's possible, but just as you commented in the first comment, I wouldn't do that for a task like that.